# branch name does not conform to git standards: refs/heads/master

Tags: git, powershell, github, git-bash, git-fast-import

This error occurred while piping the output of powershell script to git fast import. The detailed error report is as follows:

> D:\demo_history7 [master +4 ~0 -0 !]> .\testscript.ps1 -CSVFileName
>   Report_Recent.csv |git fast-import fatal: Branch name doesn't conform
>   to GIT standards: refs/heads/master fast-import: dumping crash report
>   to .git/fast_import_crash_5968

So what is the cause of this error and how can I resolve it ?

Git fast import is not recognizing the output of powershell script. That's why itz showing the error:branch name does not conform to git standards: refs/heads/master.
I am trying to pipe the output of this script to git fast-import, in order to display the history of the respective file in git remote repository, but getting the above error(as mentioned in question).My powershell script is given in the below answer.
Please provide a solution.

---

This is my powershell script:

## Script for traversing through csv file

```
[CmdletBinding(SupportsShouldProcess=$true)]
Param
(
    [string] $CSVFileName 
)

# Readthe contents of the CSV file in a single shot
#Write-Output "CSV File Name is $CSVFileName"
$CSVFileContents = Import-Csv $CSVFileName

# Iterate through each file(column) in the list
foreach($CSVFile in $CSVFileContents)
{
    # Get the parameters related to each file(column)
    $FileVersion    = $CSVFile."File Version"
    $Owner          = $CSVFile.Owner
    $UpdateDate     = $CSVFile."Update Date"
    $FileName       = $CSVFile.Filename
    $Specification  = $CSVFile.Specification
    $ProjectFolder  = $CSVFile."Project Folder"

    #Get the string size of the path
    $FolderName = "D:\demo_history\" + $ProjectFolder + $FileVersion + "_" + $FileName + "\" +  $FileVersion + "_" + $FileName
    $FolderName = $FolderName.Replace("/","\")
    $count = $FolderName.length

    #Get contents of the file,display the contents  and get size
    $Filecontent = Get-Content D:\demo_history2\RMS\APP\RSS\src\com\retek\stores\transfers\states\1_SearchTransferState.java\SearchTransferState.java


    $Getitemsize = Get-Item D:\demo_history2\RMS\APP\RSS\src\com\retek\stores\transfers\states\1_SearchTransferState.java\SearchTransferState.java
    $Length = $Getitemsize.length


    $getmark=Write-Output "mark :$FileVersion"
    $Comment = "from Serena Dimensions by $Owner on $UpdateDate"
    $Sample = $ProjectFolder + $FileVersion + "_" + $FileName + "\" +  $FileVersion + "_" + $FileName
    $Sample = $Sample.Replace("/","\")
    $Mode = "M 644 inline $Sample"

    #printing output
    Write-Output "commit refs/heads/master\r\n"
    Write-Output "$getmark"
    Write-Output "committer $Owner <$UpdateDate> -62167239000 -0700"
    Write-Output "data $count"
    Write-Output "$Comment"
    Write-Output "$Mode"
    Write-Output "data $Length"
    Write-Output "$Filecontent"

}
```

I am trying to pipe the output of this script to git fast-import, in order to display the history of the respective file in git remote repository, but getting the above error(as mentioned in question). Please provide a solution.

Comment: What is this script?  Is it something you're developing?  Are you using Unix line endings?  Are you trying to create a brand name that is `refs/heads/master\r`?  (With a Windows carriage return at the end of the name, because lines are being delimited with `\r\n`?)

Comment: Hi Edward,
 I haven't used carriage returns at the end of the name.

Comment: You don't have to go out of your way to do it.  You've used `Write-Output`, which adds a newline.  A newline on Windows is `\r\n`.  Look at the file your script is producing with a hex editor and you will see it.

Answer (score 0):

The branch name `testscript.ps1` consists of some invalid characters for a branch name in git.

A Git branch name can not include the following characters.:

```
- Have a path component that begins with "."

- Have a double dot ".."

- Have an ASCII control character, "~", "^", ":" or SP, anywhere

- End with a "/"

- End with ".lock"

- Contain a "\" (backslash
```